# Remove Multiple Record With Same Order Number

Tags: sql-server

I want to remove records with same order number.
For Example if i have 10 Products with same order number.When i want to delete these ten rows with order number it shows an error like this.

```
DELETE  FROM [NORTHWND].[dbo].[Orders]
WHERE EmployeeID = 5
```

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 22 The DELETE statement conflicted
>   with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Order_Details_Orders". The conflict
>   occurred in database "NORTHWND", table "dbo.Order Details", column
>   'OrderID'. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: That is the whole point of foreign key constraints: they stop you deleting data that is referred to elsewhere in order to maintain referential integrity:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153351/delete-statement-conflicted-with-the-reference-constraint

Comment: What about the error do you not understand? You said you want to delete orders with duplicate order numbers, but you're referencing the `EmployeeID` here, not the `OrderID`

Comment: just the example

Comment: You need to first delete their order details before deleting those orders.

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear to you?

Comment: Maybe you should learn relational database concept before attempting to delete something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to delete the records from the Orders table, first you have to delete the records from the "Order Details" table because they're not allowed to refer to a record that does not exist.

```
DELETE  FROM [NORTHWND].[dbo].[Order Details]
WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT OrderID FROM [NORTHWND].[dbo].[Order] WHERE EmployeeID = 5)
```

Then, unless there are more restrictions, you can proceed to delete the record from the Order table.

```
DELETE  FROM [NORTHWND].[dbo].[Order]
WHERE EmployeeID = 5
```

Answer (score -1):

Cannot delete bcoz have a relation with ID in table Order_Details(OrderDetails)

```
DELETE FROM Order_Details WHERE OrderId IN (SELECT ID FROM Orders WHERE EmployeeId = 5)
DELETE FROM Orders WHERE EmployeeId = 5
```